# Apache22 not serving django1.8 static files

Tags: python, django, apache, static, django-staticfiles

I have been trying to get Apache22 serve static files for my Django1.8 application. I got **mod_wsgi** working to serve my application; however, once it does the css and js files are not present.

This is my settings static items:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', 'C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/public'),
)
```

This is what I have in my Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static​​/assets/ "C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/public"
    <Directory  "C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/public">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>

     #WSGIScriptAlias...
     #....more
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my template I have :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "assets/css/style.css" %}"></script>
```

When I manually go to the URL, `127.0.0.1/static/assets/css/style.css` it just serves the default HTML page. Almost as if it cannot find the the route for that CSS file so it serves the default page again.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Alias /static​​/assets/ "C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/public"
```

to:

```
Alias /static​​/assets/ "C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/public/"
```

You must match the trailing slash on URL and file path if you are going to add a slash.

So, either on both, or not on either.

Comment: No, unfortunately that did not help. I've also tried both with out trailing slashes, which also didn't work.

Comment: Why are you mounting it as '/static​​/assets/' to begin with? Normally you would mount it at what is defined by ``START_URL``. When you run ``python manage.py collectstatic`` then files should be copied into ``STATIC_ROOT`` at the right sub directory. Check the Django documentation.

Comment: I have read the docs, that's why it works when I run it with the Django development server. It's getting Apache to serve the files, that's the question...

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Why mount it at '/static/assets' when the documentation says to use '/static'? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: And that should have been ``STATIC_URL`` above and not ``START_URL``. Stupid auto correct.

Comment: Because I am using that namespace 'assets' to store my static files. I had initially tried /static/ and now I just tried /static, but to no avail. I will try and remove that namespace to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: After you run collectstatic look in C:/Users/name/Documents/app/DRF/app/static. There should be a subdirectory 'assets'. Apache though should only be pointed at the parent directory of 'assets' with '/static' as sub URL. Apache will worry about traversing into the sub directories to match files.

Comment: Yeah that definitely sounds like something Apache would do. Okay so I finally got Apache to serve my app and the corresponding static files. The problem was that I had a url pattern in my Django app to catch all: `url(r'^.*$', views.index),` which was before the url that serves static files `
`url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,}),` and this was the only thing I changed to get it to work, silly mistake on my part. Odd that the development server didn't cause any such issues. Thanks for the help Graham!

Comment: I can't see how that would make a difference as Apache would be serving up the static files and the requests would never get passed to the Django application. If you had to do that it would suggest you may still not have the Apache configuration right. Did you change the Alias directive first argument to '/static'?